# Update after getting all records using Web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, webservice-client

I just want to know is there a way to select records and return it as list from a table then after it's done, there will be an update script. Can I create a script using only 1 web service

I'm using C# and I have only 1 table to select and update

```
Table
Column1
Column2
column3
Status
```

The status values are 0 and 1, I want to retrieve all records with 0 value using web service then update it as 1 if the retrieval is finished

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I need to see the code

Comment: Are you using asp.net or asp-classic (pre .Net)  You have tagged the question with both, I've removed asp-classic.